# Store unmodified text content in database

Tags: text

I'd like to write my Posts (and other users their Comments) in plain text and let a Markdown engine run on it later. However the Editor seems to convert the text and replaces some characters when saving etc..

Is there a way to store and retrieve the plain text from the users input in the database and get it unchanged back for further manual editing?

I already disabled the visual editor. Maybe WP got some hooks running on this, that I have to disable?

I'm using this in *functions.php* right now:

```
/* * * [Markdown] * * */
$bada_md_path = get_template_directory() . '/ext/Markdown/Michelf/';

require_once( $bada_md_path . 'MarkdownExtra.inc.php' );

use Michelf\MarkdownExtra;

function bada_md_content( $content )
{
    $content = Michelf\MarkdownExtra::defaultTransform( $content );

    return '###</br>' . $content . '</br>###';
}

add_filter( 'comment_text' , 'bada_md_content' );
add_filter( 'the_content' , 'bada_md_content' );
```

Comment: You can filter the content before saving and/or before displaying it, but in your case you should think about totally disable visual editor as visual editor is for edit HTML in visual mode and you don't want it.

Comment: In fact I copy'n'paste the plain markdown text to the editor (the code editor, not the visual one). This input-text I want to store and retrieve in the database. When I display this text I let run a MD engine over it and edit it further. The same applies to the comments.

Comment: Can you post an example of text with characters being replaced so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Whitespace gets removed, the `-` (minus) sign gets replaced by another one thats not compatible etc..

Comment: I'm sorry but I can not reproduce you issue with that information. I've written in text mode a text, minus sign and whitspaces and that characters are not replaced by any other characters.

Comment: Mhh, thank you for testing, seems to be my fault then, ill investigate abit more

Comment: Yes, the minus sign and whitspaces are there in the front end (but wrapped by `<p>` tags added by wpautop that you know already how to remove as explained in Cristian's answer) but the characters are not replaced by any other. Please, provide an exact way to reproduce the issue with a core theme and with all plugins disabled. With whitespaces, do you mean indentation or whitespaces at beginning of lines? That whitespaces at the beinning of new lines are hidden by default CSS on almost all broswers, but nothing to do with WordPress.

Comment: It was my fault, I didn't removed the filters from the `'comment_text'` and therefore it replaced every `--` beforehand and merged it back to the text. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to this:

```
function my_formatter($content) {
       $new_content = '';
       $pattern_full = '{(\[raw\].*?\[/raw\])}is';
       $pattern_contents = '{\[raw\](.*?)\[/raw\]}is';
       $pieces = preg_split($pattern_full, $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

       foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
               if (preg_match($pattern_contents, $piece, $matches)) {
                       $new_content .= $matches[1];
               } else {
                       $new_content .= wptexturize(wpautop($piece));
               }
       }


       return $new_content;
}

remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');

add_filter('the_content', 'my_formatter', 99);
```

Basically, what this does it alters the existing [raw] shortcode and by wrapping your content inside this shortcode, WordPress **should** stop messing with your code :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you knwo where I can find all filters/modifiers/actions etc that are applied to `the_content` (or the comments or more general the text from a user)?

Comment: These are basically all of them :)

Comment: I removed the same filters from `'comment_text'` and now everything seems to be as as I'd like it to be. Thanks again

Comment: Glad that helped you out @Serthy